# Use Results From Aggregate Mongoose Queries While Also Checking for Matches (Mongoose/Express)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a users and posts collections:

```js
const posts = [
  {post_id: "123abc", author_id: "cba321", body: "postdatastuff"},
  {post_id: "456def", author_id: "fed654", body: "postdatastuff"},
  {post_id: "789hij", author_id: "fed654", body: "postdatastuff"},
  {post_id: "101klm", author_id: "mlk101", body: "postdatastuff"},
]

const users = [
  {user_id: "cba321", liked_posts: ["123abc", "456def"]},
  {user_id: "fed654", liked_posts: ["789hij", "123abc"]},
  {user_id: "jih987", liked_posts: ["456def", "123abc", "789hij"]},
]
```

If I am signed in as user "cba321", and I would like to return all the posts user "fed654", while also checking to see if I have liked each of their posts, how would I write a mongoose aggregate query to achieve this?

This aggregate function would return:

```js
const posts = [
      {post_id: "456def", author_id: "fed654", body: "postdatastuff", liked: true},
      {post_id: "789hij", author_id: "fed654", body: "postdatastuff", liked: false},
];
```

Currently, I am writing this without mongoose aggregation. Not only does my solution not work, but it's not very efficient since it must return the values to the server and process through them in 2 separate processes and I would like for it to be a single 100% mongoose native aggregate function.

Heres my attempt:

```js
router.post("path", async (req, res) => {
  const reqUser = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.u_id }).lean(); //gets requesting users user information
  const user = await User.findOne({ uName: req.body.uName }).lean(); //gets the url's path userName user information.
  const posts = await Post.find({ a_id: user._id }).lean(); //gets all the posts from the previously searched user
  const resData = posts.map((p) => {
    return {
      ...p,
      author_name: user.name, //combines the users name as the author name with each post
      author_uName: user.uName,
      liked: reqUser.likes.indexOf(p._id), //checks to see if the requesting user has liked the post
    };
  });
  res.status(200).json(resData);
});
```

And this function returns something like:

```js
]   
   {
     _id: 123abc,
     body: 'testbodytext',
     author_id: 'cba321',
     a_name: 'test',
     a_uName: 'test',
     liked: -1
   }
 ]
```

This aggregate of queries replicates youtube or twitters functionality when you view another users page/profile where it displays that users posts and if you have liked them or not.

Basically, this function takes a single _id from a user/author from the user's collection and uses it to search through the posts collection for any author_id's that match. It will then return all the posts that match while checking if the requesting user has liked each post or not.

I'm looking for an answer that isn't javascript, promised, async or waterfall method based.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I am signed in as user "cba321", and I would like to return all the
> posts user "fed654", while also checking to see if I have liked each
> of their posts, ...

You query the `users` collection and provide the two input variables - signed in user and the author/user whose posts you liked - to get the desired result. The query runs in `mongo` shell, to return the following result:

```
{
        "post_id" : "456def",
        "author_id" : "fed654",
        "body" : "postdatastuff",
        "liked" : true
}
```

*The aggregation query:*

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { 
      $match: { user_id: "cba321" }    // <-- signed in user
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$liked_posts" 
  },
  {
      $lookup: {
          from: "posts",
          let: { likedPost: "$liked_posts" },
          pipeline: [
              {  $match: { 
                      $expr: { 
                          $and: [
                              { $eq: [ "$post_id", "$$likedPost" ] },
                              { $eq: [ "fed654", "$author_id" ] }    // <-- posts for a specified user/author
                          ]
              } } }
          ],
          as: "matched_posts",
      }
  },
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$matched_posts" }, 0 ] } 
      } 
  },
  {
      $unwind: "$matched_posts"
  },
  { 
      $replaceWith: "$matched_posts" 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          _id: "$$REMOVE",
          liked: true
      } 
  },
])
```